# ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, protocolexception

Retrofit network calls fails with a Protocol Exception suddenly in a working app.
The app was working till yesterday and today all the network calls fails. The calls works fine with HTTP but fails with HTTPS.

Here is the logs,

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http2xStream.readHttp2HeadersList(Http2xStream.java:262)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http2xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http2xStream.java:145)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:53)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at codmob.com.campuswallet.app.ApiClient$1.intercept(ApiClient.java:66)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
10-18 14:59:01.103 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-18 14:59:01.104 30746-30746/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Have you resolved this already?

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/49643383/3448003

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After hours of mess, finally got a solution. Updating Retrofit and Okhttp3 libraries to the latest version did the trick for me.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

Comment: By using this fix my problem still exist.

Comment: This is not fix if your app is in production - users continue to experience issue until they update. @aradon answer explains reason and more appropriate will be both downgrade nginx and update oktthp.

Answer (score 10):

I am using `OkHttp2` (2.7.5) and I solved this issue by forcing the client to use `HTTP 1.1` protocol

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)); // <- add this line
```

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: @BajrangHudda this line means that your `OkHttp` client will not try to use `http2` protocol when is available. You just have to put this line into your client app source code and release a new version to production. That's it.

Comment: ok, I got your point. But why app suddenly stop working? Yesterday it was working on same device but today it can work only by setting Protocol.Http.1.1. Why so?

Comment: @BajrangHudda maybe you or someone updated server engine to version, which supports `http2` protocol. This was my reason.

Comment: if it was the reason then, how problem solved by setting protocol http1.1? I am a bit confused, can you explain in detail?

Comment: And app with android device 4.4.2 still running fine without setting protocol http1.1.

Comment: @BajrangHudda This is my idea: `http2` is new protocol and it seems older Android does not support it - so `OkHttp2` uses only `http1.1` which is working well. Newer Android versions support `http2` and `OkHttp2` (which does not handle `http2` well) makes a decision "let's use this new `http2` protocol because is available on a server" - and that's why it is not working.

Answer (score 8):

Today faced the same problem. The reason was in updating nginx on the server to the latest version (1.13.6). Ask your backend team if they did not update nginx on the server.

nginx changelog - http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

Comment: Post relevant parts of the linked page in the answer so that even if the page changes, the answer is still useful.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Updating to the latest version of okhttp3 (3.9.0) and retrofit2 (2.3,0) did the trick for me.

Comment: But I am using sucuri, What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

I am using okhttp3 (okhttp-3.4.1), okhttp3 is not very compatible with the HTTP_1.1 protocol and needs to be manually added. you can see [Official link](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html)

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
//protocols
List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<Protocol>();
protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_2);
builder.protocols(protocols);
```