# Picasso java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, picasso, android-bitmap

I am getting `java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present` on few images when loading them from `picasso`.

If i open the image from browser it loads fine.

The is how i am loading the images.

```
                          Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL)
                                    .fit()
                                    .centerInside()
                                    .into(ivNews, new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {
                                            //Display Message
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError() {
                                            Log.d(ERROR, "something went wrong");
                                        }
                                    });
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1724), this isn't picasso fault, but what possible steps i can take to avoid this issue, and load image if this type of problems occurs on server side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807237/protocolexception-expected-status-header-not-present

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem before :
If you are using Retrofit then try updating it to the latest version
as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807237/protocolexception-expected-status-header-not-present)